# Reuse same "block" of html in multiple django templates

Tags: django, html, django-templates

Currently, I have two html template that extends from a base.html:

page1.html:

```
{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% block tittle %} Dashboard1 {% endblock %}
... code ...
Code_block_1
{% endblock %}
```

page2.html:

```
{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% block tittle %} Dashboard2 {% endblock %}
... code ...
Code_block_1
{% endblock %}
```

Both html share the same Code_block_1.

I was thinking about about creating another html called Code_block_1.html to consolidate this repeating piece of code. Then, insert Code_block_1.html into page1.html and pag2.html.  Django only lets you extend once.  How do I get around this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply create another HTML file called `code_block_1.html` and then inside both `page1.html` and `page2.html` use [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include) like this:

```
<!-- page1.html -->

{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% block tittle %} Dashboard1 {% endblock %}
... code ...
{% include 'code_block_1.html' %}
{% endblock %}


<!-- page2.html -->

{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% block tittle %} Dashboard2 {% endblock %}
... code ...
{% include 'code_block_1.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This perfect! Thanks!